# Hypergeometric transformations

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, transformation, hypergeometric-function

Denoting $_2F_1(a,b;c;z)$ as the hypergeometric function we have
$$
_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(a)_{k}(b)_{k}}{(c)_{k}} \frac{z^{k}}{k !},\quad |z|<1.
$$

Euler's transformation is
$$
{ }_{2} F_{1}(a, b ; c ; z)=(1-z)^{c-a-b}{ }_{2} F_{1}(c-a, c-b ; c ; z)
$$
and two Pfaff transformations are
$$
\begin{aligned}
&{ }_{2} F_{1}(a, b ; c ; z)=(1-z)^{-b}{ }_{2} F_{1}\left(b, c-a ; c ; \frac{z}{z-1}\right), \\
&{ }_{2} F_{1}(a, b ; c ; z)=(1-z)^{-a}{ }_{2} F_{1}\left(a, c-b ; c ; \frac{z}{z-1}\right),
\end{aligned}
$$
respectively.

**My question:**

What is its condition **for a,b,c parameters?** Can c is equal a ? or a,b and c is equal zero in transformations?

Comment: The main condition is: the equalities hold for $z$ such that both of the series converge.  So, if we like, we can think of one side providing an analytic continuation of the other side.  The condition to watch out for: if $c$ is a nonpositive integer, then you could get $0$ in the denominator when $(c)_k = 0$.  (If one of $a,b$ is also a nonpositive integer, then sometimes we can make sense of the series by allowing cancellation with the denominator.)

Comment: My go-to reference for most functions is K. Oldham, J. Myland, & J. Spanier, *An Atlas of Functions*, Springer . Chapter 60 covers the Gauss Hypergeometric Function. The cases you are looking at are there along with several others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, these work under the conditions you ask about.

**Can $a$ equal $c$?**
$$
{}_2 F_1(a,b;a;z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(b)_k z^k}{k!} = (1-z)^{-b}
\\
{}_2 F_1(0,a-b;a;z) = 1
\\
{}_2 F_1\left(b,0;a;\frac{z}{z-1}\right) = 1
\\
{}_2 F_1\left(a,a-b;a;\frac{z}{z-1}\right) = \left(1-\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^{-a+b}
$$
Then your three equations become:
$$
(1-z)^{-b} = (1-z)^{-b}
\\
(1-z)^{-b} = (1-z)^{-b}
\\
(1-z)^{-b} = (1-z)^{-a}\left(1-\frac{z}{z-1}\right)^{-a+b}
$$
which are correct.

**can $a, b$, or $c$ be zero?**

As explained in a comment, $c$ cannot be $0$ unless one of $a,b$ is also $0$.  For example
$$
{}_2 F_1(1,1;0;z)\qquad\text{is no good}
$$
But
$$
{}_2 F_1(0,b;0;z) = (1-z)^{-b}
$$
The numerator $(0)_k$ cancels the denominator $(0)_k$.

Comment: Woow :) its a very clear answer and a clever approach. what you said were not written anywhere in such details. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Find everything you (or at least I) want to know about hypergeometric functions: two chapters in *Special Functions* by Andrews, Askey  & Roy.

Comment: Hah I was just looking up some (generalized) hypergeometric function asymptotic expansions for research purposes and this popped up on the top of MSE. GEdgar has a great answer as always, but if you want to know more, check out the NIST (Digital) Handbook of Mathematical Functions @user1062 https://dlmf.nist.gov/15.2 . It's a fantastic repository for mathematical knowledge. It's hard to beat when it comes to the theory of special functions. There are others like A&S which are much more detailed, but NIST is much more friendly.

Comment: thanks for your advice:) Its a good guide. Good luck. @CameronWilliams